# Why doesn't "python" command work in virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Before asking, I should mention that this is NOT a problem or a bug, this is just a question to widen my knowledge.

When I was working on a Django project (I'm quite new to all these things so don't beat, please) I activated my virtualenv, installed `django` module and started a new Django project by using `django-admin.py startproject myproject` . That worked. But then I `cd` to `myproject` and tried to run `python manage.py startapp firstapp`, and failed.

I caught `ImportError: no module named 'django'`. The problem was solved by simply typing `./manage.py startapp firstapp` . What the heck is that? Why doesn't `python` command work? Python version is 3.5.2.

Comment: Did you install django on your `virtualEvn`?

Comment: did you install django via `pip`? what you see if you type `pip freeze` in your activated virtualenv?

Comment: @deathangel908 @Juraj I've installed django exactly in virtualenv via `pip`. `pip freeze` output: `Django==1.10.5 uWSGI==2.0.14` (I do not think uwsgi is important)

Comment: The python command works. Like it says, it can't find the module `django`. So the python you started is not able to find Django. Is your env activated? If you type `which python` it should show your env python. Eg `path/to/env/bin/python` the same for `which pip`, it should give `path/to/env/bin/pip`.

Comment: Also Django should be installed with the env supplied pip. So in `path/to/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages` should be a django module (a folder named django).

Comment: @allcaps yes, the output is correct and env is activated, but `python manage.py` still doesn't work. The funniest thing is, django is installed and `django-admin` works fine, but manage.py is like an exception. I've tried deleting the first line in manage.py (like `#! /usr/bin/env python`) - no luck. And there IS django in site-packages

Comment: @RyanSnow Have you added python command on your environment variable as a path ? Do you use Windows ?

Comment: @KasimovNuriddin yes I have

Comment: What does `which django-admin` give you? I guess a system installed django-admin and not the one in your env right? Just install Django in your env. Make sure all commands like `pip install ...` and `django-admin ...` are run with your env activated `source env/bin/activate`. Then `python manage.py ...` will work as well.

Comment: @allcaps again, that's funny, but I'm 100% sure I run my env django, `which django-admin` makes me even more sure. Everything is clear. Env is activated

Comment: To better understand virtualenv try http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/01/virtualenv-demystified/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way virtualenvs work, Django was not 'installed' in said env.

The reason `./manage.py startapp firstapp` worked is because the `./` indicated that it was an executable file, and hence handled by the system as such. That way, modules are accessible, as the program is ran outside of the env

Hope this helped!

Comment: I think I should consider your answer as the right one. Still that seems a bit weired to me, but thank you anyway